# How do I install uuidgen

Tags: linux, debian

I need `uuidgen` for my Linux shell scripts, but it's not on my Debian 7.1 net install.

`apt-get install uuidgen` fails, it's not clear what package I should be using, and existing questions seem to ask for alternatives rather than the real `uuidgen`.

Could someone with experience with uuidgen comment on where to get it, and why it's not in its own package?

PS. Repost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710958/how-do-i-install-uuidgen?noredirect=1#comment25824003_17710958

Comment: Next time just use the [web-based package search function](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=uuidgen&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The package [uuid-runtime](http://packages.debian.org/sid/uuid-runtime) contains the uuidgen program.

> This package contains the uuidgen program and the uuidd daemon.

Comment: Used `apt-get install uuid-runtime`

Comment: If you get the error message  "Package uuid-runtime is not available, but is referred to by another package." etc make sure to first run `apt-get update` (both likely also require `sudo`)

Answer (score 2):

To add to [loop's answer](https://superuser.com/a/621300/399707), install with:

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-runtime
```

It is probably best to run an update prior to installing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

These commands are taken from info in the comments by [Donal](https://superuser.com/questions/621297/how-do-i-install-uuidgen/621300#comment772202_621300) and [Oskar](https://superuser.com/questions/621297/how-do-i-install-uuidgen/621300#comment2654413_621300)